# AngularJS Full Stack form Submit Issue

Tags: angularjs

I have included on extra input field to the default login.html page available in yeoman+express+angularjs full stack application

```
 <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="login(form)" novalidate>
`<input type="text" name="pname" class="form-control" ng-model="user.pname" >` 
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password">
<p class="help-block" ng-show="form.pname.$error.required && form.email.$error.required &&              form.password.$error.required  && submitted"><button type="submit" lass="btn btn-info">Sign in</button></div>
```

but pname is not getting validated for blank and im not able to get the value of pname in my controller also

```
angular.module('ratefastApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.errors = {};

    $scope.login = function(form) {
      $scope.submitted = true;

      if(form.$valid) {
        Auth.login({
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password,
          practicename : $scope.user.pname
        })
        .then( function(err) {
          $location.path('/');
        })
        .catch( function(err) {          
          err = err.data;
          $scope.errors.other = err.message;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

pname is going undefined.. in express controller , my express controller code is as follow

> exports.login = function (req, res, next)  { var
>
> > practiceName = String(req.body.pname);   var userName =
> >     String(req.body.email);   var userPass = String(req.body.password); };
> >
> > ------------- route.js app.post('/api/session', session.login);
> >     ------- html is same as above
> >
> > in console im getting practiceName  undefined

Comment: you're passing `practicename`, not `pname`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `required` on the fields you need:

```
<input type="text" name="pname" class="form-control" ng-model="user.pname" required>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UenRaVOCDLNAa1NiUA89?p=preview)

The reason you get `undefined` for your `pname` in your express controller is because you're passing `practicename`, not `pname`:

```
Auth.login({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password,
      practicename : $scope.user.pname //you use practicename here.
 })
```

Try replacing:

```
practiceName = String(req.body.pname);
```

With:

```
practiceName = String(req.body.practicename);
```

Comment: but what about the parameter pname im not getting in express controller by using req.body.pname , rest of the parameters are available req.body.email , req.body.password

Comment: @sergioramosiker: You need to provide more code, I reproduced your current code in the DEMO and you can see that `pname` is available.

Comment: controller side code
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  var practiceName = String(req.body.pname);
  var userName = String(req.body.email);
  var userPass = String(req.body.password);
};
-------------
route.js
app.post('/api/session', session.login);
-------
html is same as above 

in console im getting practiceName  undefined

Comment: @sergioramosiker: can you update your question with that information? It's easier to see and also help future visitors.